# number sorting function python not working (selection sort)

Tags: python, list, sorting, while-loop, numbers

```
nums = [554, 565, 367, 69, 869, 965, 506, 136, 913, 463, 987, 315, 967, 35]
print(nums)
y=0
x=0
min=nums[x]
while y<len(nums):
  while x<len(nums):
    if min>nums[x]:
      c=x
      min=nums[c]
    x=x+1
  x=0
  tmp=nums[y]
  nums[0]=min
  y+=1
  min=tmp

print(nums)
```

I am confused why this code doesnt sort the numbers from lowest to highest. I am supposed to do selection sort

Answer (score 0):

Change the `x=0` to `x=y+1`. This is a selection sort and you might check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) for help.

EDIT:
  change algorithm link to selection sort.

Comment: Which x=0 should I change to x=y+1? or both? I am supposed to do selection sort.

Comment: the one in the loop content. every time you are selecting from all items which means every time you are selecting the smallest item in the whole array rather than the rest of un-sorted array(i.e., from y to len(nums) ).  Really sorry about a wrong algorithm link.